# Randomized algorithm to estimate $\pi$

Tags: circles, uniform-distribution, pi, monte-carlo, simulation

I was looking for an algorithm to create a PI estimator, and I ran across this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659034/trying-to-create-a-pi-estimator-in-r

Briefly, the steps are:

```
(1) set j equal to 0.
(2) start a for loop with counter i that repeats N times.
(3) Inside the for loop, generate two random uniform numbers x and y between -1 and +1 using runif().
(4) If x^2 + y^2 < 1 then add one to j.
(5) End the for loop.
(6) Return the estimate of π which is 4×j/N
```

Can someone please explain me the logic behind the sampling of uniform distribution?
And why these steps actually gives estimate to PI?

Thank you!

Comment: Not mentioned in the existing answer is that this is a ridiculously dumb way of estimating π. Far better would be to count the number of lattice points within a circle of radius n plus half the number of lattice points exactly on the circle, and then divide that by the total area of a square of side 2n. With a bit of thinking, you can count this in O(n) time, getting an estimate of π with error O(1/n). In contrast, your cited randomized algorithm gives a random estimate of π with standard deviation Θ(1/√n)!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [monte carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration)  algorithm that finds the area of a circle of radius 1 inside a square with side 2. You   choose a random point in the square and see whether it is inside the circle. The proportion of points inside the circle will approximate the area of the  circle ($\pi$) over the area of the square,  $4$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler The OP doesn't say, but it's implicit in the pseudocode that they are choosing $x$ and $y$ uniformly from $[0,1]$. That's why they multiply by 4 at the end.

Comment: @DanielSchepler It does. I missed it because my browser window was too narrow. In that case multiplying by 4 in the last step is an error.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Fixed my answer while you were writing the last comment. Thanks.